# FileOutputStream

Tags: java, xlsx

```
   public FileOutputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(name != null ? new File(name) : null, false);
    }
public FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        this(name != null ? new File(name) : null, append);
    }
public FileOutputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(file, false);
    }
 public FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String name = (file != null ? file.getPath() : null);
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null) {
            security.checkWrite(name);
        }
        if (name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (file.isInvalid()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid file path");
        }
        this.fd = new FileDescriptor();
        this.append = append;
        this.path = name;
        fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
        open(name, append);
    }
  public FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor fdObj) {
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (fdObj == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (security != null) {
            security.checkWrite(fdObj);
        }
        this.fd = fdObj;
        this.path = null;
        this.append = false;
   fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
    }
vate native void open(String name, boolean append)
        throws FileNotFoundException;
private native void write(int b, boolean append) throws IOException;
  public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        Object traceContext = IoTrace.fileWriteBegin(path);
        int bytesWritten = 0;
        try {
            write(b, append);
            bytesWritten = 1;
        } finally {
            IoTrace.fileWriteEnd(traceContext, bytesWritten);
        }
    }
private native void writeBytes(byte b[], int off, int len, boolean append)
        throws IOException;
 public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
        Object traceContext = IoTrace.fileWriteBegin(path);
        int bytesWritten = 0;
        try {
            writeBytes(b, 0, b.length, append);
            bytesWritten = b.length;
        } finally {
            IoTrace.fileWriteEnd(traceContext, bytesWritten);
        }
    }
public void close() throws IOException {
        synchronized (closeLock) {
            if (closed) {
                return;
            }
            closed = true;
        }

        if (channel != null) {
nt useCount = fd.decrementAndGetUseCount();

        if ((useCount <= 0) || !isRunningFinalize()) {
            close0();
        }
    }

     public final FileDescriptor getFD()  throws IOException {
        if (fd != null) return fd;
        throw new IOException();

    public FileChannel getChannel() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (channel == null) {
                channel = FileChannelImpl.open(fd, path, false, true, append, this);
                fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
            }
            return channel;
        }
    }

    protected void finalize() throws IOException {
        if (fd != null) {
            if (fd == FileDescriptor.out || fd == FileDescriptor.err) {
                flush();
            } else {

                runningFinalize.set(Boolean.TRUE);
                try {
                    close();
                } finally {
                    runningFinalize.set(Boolean.FALSE);
      }
    }

    private native void close0() throws IOException;

    private static native void initIDs();

    static {
        initIDs();
```

### }

**Stack Trace**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\webs\Softparam2\upload\1\1429175417820\cfm\CFM_test.xlsx (Le périphérique n’est pas prêt)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutput)
```

Comment: Does the file `D:\webs\Softparam2\upload\1\1429175417820\cfm\CFM_test.xlsx` exist?

Comment: its really simple that your file doesn't exist on that path... if it does.. you are not allowed to access it...

Comment: We need information about what you have tried and an actual question
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i wont de upload this file from the bdd

Comment: at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
 at net.atos.softparam.util.CsvGenerator.createCfmFile(CsvGenerator.java:854)
 at net.atos.softparam.util.CsvGenerator.createFiles(CsvGenerator.java:227)

Comment: path += "cfm/";
  new File(path).mkdirs();
  try{
      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path+"CFM_"+storeBrand.getName()+".xlsx");
      wb.write(fileOut);
      fileOut.close();
  }catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return errors.toString();
 }

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` is typically thrown when a file does not exist. I'd suggest you check the filepath.

As a general rule, it is a bad idea to use absolute filepaths. Instead, place the file required in the current working folder (can be found with `System.getProperty("user.dir");`) and simply call: `FileInputStream("CFM_test.xlsx");`

Comment: path += "cfm/"; new File(path).mkdirs(); try{ FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path+"CFM_"+storeBrand.getName()+".xlsx"); wb.write(fileOut); fileOut.close(); }catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); } return errors.toString(); }    what the path reprensent ?? chemin of file ?

Comment: The `System.getProperty("user.dir");` returns a string with the current working directory.

Working Directory is the term given to the directory in which the application is running from. E.G. C:\Program Files\eclipse-luna\workbench

You can use this simple command to set a file path for an application dependencie like so:

`final String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + <your file here>;`
`FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);`

Then simply move the file to the same directory displayed by `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`